# cascading dropdown using ajax Php and mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am creating something like this and have a problem one of the dropdown. You get better understanding by the video

[Video for the reference](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxawGn4TxUFBeFJXVnljUjFjQTQ/view?usp=sharing)

[here the source code file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxawGn4TxUFBV0RXTlRCTmdObzA/view?usp=sharing)

[here the tutorial link](http://buffernow.com/cascading-dropdown-ajax/?q=nocache&q=nocache)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you're receving the AJAX data, you're always adding it to the next dropdown. However, you're not clearing the dropdown before you do so, and therefore you get the previous items as well.

To fix it for the Type->Model dropdowns for example (as shown in the video), you should start your `populateModel()` with an `empty()` call like this:

```
function populateModel(xmlindata) {

  var mySelect = $('#printermodel');;
  mySelect.empty();
```